# Windows XP and auto re-login

Tags: windows-xp, login

How to enforce autologin not just first time when computer boots, but even if user click logoff.

So everytime when user clicks logoff, he is immediately loged back.

Comment: That would be an undesirable feature from an administrative standpoint. Any admin why wants needs to log into the box to work on it will need to log out of the locked down user and log in to the admin account to make changes or updates wouldn’t be able to due to that being enabled.

Comment: I saw this on some embeded winXP box. When you powerd on the computer you get logged directly into user account. When you cklicked log off you have been logged of and the imidiatly loged in back again.
For accessing the administrator account you have had to press and hold shift key and then click logof.
This way you get the normal windows login dialog.

Comment: [Please do not cross-post.](http://serverfault.com/questions/243613/win-xp-and-auto-login)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you already configured the "AutoAdminLogon" key along with the "DefaultPassword" and "DefaultUserName" keys in the appropriate "WinLogon" branch in your Windows Registry...

To force automatic login after a simple Logout (Logoff) operation, add a "ForceAutoLogon" (without quotation marks) string entry with the value of "1" (without quotation marks).

We used to do this on workstations connected to Novell NetWare networks for the few "special" users who couldn't resist causing a lot of computer problems.  Here's Novell's KnowledgeBase document on all the AutoAdminLogon settings:

TID 10052847 - Configure AutoAdminLogon for Novell Clients for Windows NT/2000/XP
  http://support.novell.com/docs/Tids/Solutions/10052847.html